# Extract text in front of a character in certain position

Tags: vb.net

If I have the following string:
100456,3456,1235,0,0,100,500

I need to be able to extract specific values such as 100456, 1235 and 100. I am having trouble writing code to extract text in front of a comma in a certain position.

Basically extract text in front of the 1st comma, extract text in front of the 3rd comma, etc.

```
 Dim fields() As String = Split(TextLine, ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(fields)
                If i = 0 Then
                    Value1 = fields(i)
                End If
                If i = 3 Then
                    Value2 = fields(i)
                End If
            Next
```

I've tried this, but the loop seems to run more times than it should.

Comment: I am having trouble reading the code you wrote and failed to include.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  All the smart kids would use a CSV tool or maybe `String.Split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Dim fields() As String = Split(TextLine, ",")
 Dim Value1 as String = fields(0)
 Dim Value2 as String = fields(2) 'the field in front of 3rd comma is index 2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.. looks like I was over complicating things!